# Swift protocol inheritance and associatedtype

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, associated-types

I have protocol with associatedtype

```
protocol IBaseDao {
    associatedtype Entity

    func insert(e: Entity, completion: @escaping (Result<Entity, Error>) -> Void)
    func insertReplacing(e: Entity, completion: @escaping (Result<Entity, Error>) -> Void)
    func delete(e: Entity, completion: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> Void)
    func update(e: Entity, completion: @escaping (Result<Entity, Error>) -> Void)
    func load(id: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Entity, Error>) -> Void)
    func loadAll(completion: @escaping (Result<[Entity], Error>) -> Void)
}
```

Then I want to add specific protocols for concrete entity type like so:

```
protocol IMoviesDao : IDao where Entity == Movie {

    func load(query: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Movie], Error>) -> Void)
}
```

Then I have BaseDao implementation like below:

```
class UserDefaultsDao<T> : IDao {

    typealias Entity = T
}
```

Then I have implementation of concrete Dao class:

```
class MoviesUserDefaultsDao : UserDefaultsDao<Movie>, IMoviesDao {

}
```

Finally I would like to use:

```
final class MoviesRepository {

    private let moviesService : IMoviesService
    private let moviesDao : IMoviesDao
}
```

But here I am getting error message:

> Protocol 'IMoviesDao' can only be used as a generic constraint because
>   it has Self or associated type requirements

Can I somehow workaround this issue? 
I consider that specifing the same methods again in IMoviesDao as in IBaseDao and removing protocol inheritance (extension) will do the job but then I need to rewrite this methods for each Dao protocol

**UPDATE:**

So now I need to duplicate this methods

```
protocol IMoviesDao {

    func load(query: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Movie], Error>) -> Void)

    func insert(e: Movie, completion: @escaping (Result<Movie, Error>) -> Void)
    func insertReplacing(e: Movie, completion: @escaping (Result<Movie, Error>) -> Void)
    func delete(e: Movie, completion: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> Void)
    func update(e: Movie, completion: @escaping (Result<Movie, Error>) -> Void)
    func load(id: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Movie, Error>) -> Void)
    func loadAll(completion: @escaping (Result<[Movie], Error>) -> Void)
}
```

Comment: Why do you want `IMoviesDao` to be a protocol exactly?

Comment: dependency injection, to be able to replace this MoviesDao concrete object while injecting it to repository ex. unit testing with MoviesDaoMock : IMoviesDao